# If $f$ is strictly monotonic then $f$ is one-one but the converse is not true.

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f$ is strictly monotonic then $f$ is one-one but the converse is not true.

Can someone give me an example of such function which is one-one but not strictly monotonic for proving the converse part of that statement?

Answer (score 5):

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
    x, & x\in \mathbb{Q}; \\
    -x, & x\notin \mathbb{Q} \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: Great, what a function! Now you have to draw it!::)

Answer (score 4):

Construct a discontinuous function by first considering $f(x)=x$ and then remove the part of the graph of $f$ within the interval $[0,1]$ and replace it by $f(x)=-x+1$ in that interval.

Then $f$ remains one-to-one, but it's not strictly monotonic anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting note: if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is indeed continuous and injective, then it is strictly monotonic. This is a consequence of the intermediate value theorem, applied to a few cases. For example, if we have $a < b < c$ and $f(a) < f(c) < f(b)$, then it follows that some $d$ exists between $a$ and $c$ such that $f(c) = f(d)$, but $d < b < c$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:[0,2) \to \mathbb R$ by

$f(x)=x$ , if $x \in [0,1)$ and $f(x)=x-2$, if $x \in [1,2)$.